# What is the reason for speed jumps in this Wifi transmission?

Tags: wireless-networking, udp, 802.11n

In this picture:

[image]

The X axis is time slots of 5 seconds each and the Y axis is the number of 1KiB packets transmitted in that slot. The blue graph shows the actual number of transmitted packets using UDP over Wifi 802.11n and the orange graph is the number of lost packets. The sender and receiver are 16 meters apart at a height of about 1 meter. There were other access points in the area but there was a reasonable distance from them in an open area, so the noise probably is not affecting the system that much.

My question is if this kind of jump and drop in speed every about 100 seconds is normal and related to the wifi protocol or not.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not normal, and there's nothing in 802.11 that would cause this.